# allow only numbers in textfield

Tags: magento-1.8, script

we are displaying textfield to enter zip code.

We want to validate with only numbers.

means  it should not allow to enter any alphabets or special charactars.

```
    <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" 
maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
<div id="delivery-message"></div>
```

i tried `pattern="\d{6}"` but it did't worked for me.

**Edit** - checkdelivery.phhtml full code

```
<div class="block block-list block-check-delivery">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" >        
        <br>

            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" 
maxlength="10" class="input-text validate-digits required-entry" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>


<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
<div id="delivery-message"></div>

            <div id="delivery-message"></div>
            <?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
            <div id="delivery-html"><?php if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message')){
    echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message');
}
else{
    $defaultHtml; } ?></div>

        <br>        
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress = function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){
          // Do your ajax process which you are doing on zip-check click button same way.

              new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
                    method: "get",
                    parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                             var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                             $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                             
                             $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                             $('delivery-html').update(json.html); 
                    }
            });

          return false;
        }
      }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided, you should fix `jQuery` errors first.

You should move `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` after `jquery-noconflict.js`, this will fix `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error.

**Now for answering your question**,

First, add all validation classes to your input field that suits your requirements, check [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) for full list

Now, you can validate your input field by this code :

```
if( Validation.validate($('estimate_postcode')) ){
    //VALID INPUT
}
else{
    //IN-VALID INPUT
}
```

**UPDATE**: As per your code, Do changes below:

```
<script>
Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
    if(Validation.validate($('zipcode'))){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            ...
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

AND

```
<script>
document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){
        if(Validation.validate($('zipcode'))){

            // Do your ajax process which you are doing on zip-check click button same way.
            new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
                ...
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: its not a form, it just a Delivery availability button. in this case is i need to use script ?

Comment: You can use the code posted if it's not a form. This will just validate an element which ID is passed to it. Change `estimate_postcode`, to the ID of your element being validated

Comment: please check updated question with full code of the file

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: please check link, may be i did some thing wrong.

Comment: which link ? send me here again

Comment: I can't see my code there. Note this line `if(Validation.validate($('zipcode')...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40650/discussion-between-user-7639gu59305u-and-anil-suthar).

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure following things in this case

1. Make sure `js/prototype/validation.js` is loading in your form page.
2. You need to trigger email validation through a script like this.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //< ![CDATA[
       var customForm = new VarienForm('your_form_id');
   //]]>
   </script>
   ```

   Make sure this exist in your code. If not, please add this and replace `your_form_id` with `id` property value of your form.
3. Change your input element like this.

   ```
   <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" maxlength="10" class="input-text validate-digits required-entry" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
   ```

See the `class` attribute. `validate-digits` will make sure only numbers will be passed in request and `required-entry` ensures this is a required input.

Hope that helps

Comment: I can't find `validation.js` file in your site. I didn't see `VarienForm` declaration for zip code.

Comment: please check now

Comment: its not a form, it just a Delivery availability button. in this case is i need to use script ?

Answer (score 0):

Use class "validate-digits" to restrict the input field to have the numbers only.

You can refer http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/ for other validations.

Comment: i added like this : `<input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" maxlength="6" class="input-text validate-digits" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>" pattern="\d{6}"/>
<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>` but didt worked for me

Comment: no need for pattern="\d{6}", remove and try again.

Comment: i removed it, but still no luck.

Comment: its not a form, it just a Delivery availability button. in this case is i need to use script ?

Comment: did not get ur point